# Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1 High Availability using REST API

Tags: rest, servicebus

I need to send messages to queues in a Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1 farm with three servers using the REST API.

When I'm using the .NET SDK I can just specify the three servers in the connection string like this:

```
"Endpoint=sb://machine1/test-namespace,sb://machine2/test-namespace,sb://machine3/test-namespace;StsEndpoint=https://machine1:9355/test-namespace,https://machine2:9355/test-namespace,https://machine3:9355/test-namespace;RuntimePort=9354;ManagementPort=9355"
```

Is there a way to do this in a http request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately No.
In .Net SDK - Service Bus Client does the magic of Round-Robin'ing the request to all 3 endpoints - if one of the endpoint fails. 
If you are using REST API - you will need to implement this logic.

Another solution is to use a Software loadbalancer - which can monitor the Health of 3 machines and use the software load balancer endpoint for all client communication. This way - even if one machine has a hardware failure and you needed to add another brand new machine to the farm (with a different machine name) - you will not need to update your client connection strings.

Hope it Helps!
Sree